Prove That $\int_{1}^{e}\frac{1}{t}dt=1$ Without the Use of Logarithms
I've been studying Real Analysis by Jay Cummings, and am working through the exercises on integration. The question is as such:
Define a function $L:(0, \infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $L(x)=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt$
It then goes on to prove that $L(xy)=L(x)+L(y)$ without the use of the natural logarithm et cetera... However, the final part is interesting:
Prove that $L(x^y)=yL(x)$, and hence deduce that $L(e^x)=x$. After proving the first part, $L(e^x)=xL(e)$ is trivial. However, I'm not entirely sure what they want me to do after that - just assume that $L$ is the natural logarithm and call it a day with $L(e)=1$? If so, that's very boring, but it got me thinking - how would you prove that $\int_{1}^{e}\frac{1}{t}dt=1$  without assuming that it's simply equal to $ln(e)$? And so I constructed a sequence of partitions $P_n$ with all intervals $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$ having length $\frac{e-1}{n}$, and had a look at the upper and lower Darboux sums, getting (for L):
$$\int_{1}^{e}\frac{1}{t}dt = \lim_{n \to \infty}(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{e-1}{n+k(e-1)})$$
When plugged into Wolfram Alpha, the limit equals 1 as desired. I'd like to do this without the use of a calculator, but I am absolutely stuck! Could someone help me out?
Many thanks

Which definition of $e$ are you using?  $L(e)=1$ is one of the nicest definitions, in my opinion.

Well of course that's quite circular, but it'd be lovely. I haven't formally defined e nor really thought about it - let's just use the classic limit of (1+1/n)^n and call it a day - I'm not too fussed about it though.

Would substituting $t=e^x$ into $\int_{e^0}^{e^1}\frac{dt}t$ work?

@ТymaGaidash Lovely solution! I'm going to keep this question open though because I'm still intrigued with how to solve this by using the limit of sums.

If you haven't got a definiti9n of $e,$ then you don't have a question.

$\int\limits_1^e \frac{1}{x} dx = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n(\sqrt[n]{e} -1) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n(1 + \frac{1}{n} - 1) = 1$

As mentioned, this depends on how you define $e$. If
$$
e=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(1+\frac1n\Big)^{n}, 
$$
then using that $L$ is continuous you have
\begin{align}
L(e) 
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}L\bigg(\Big(1+\frac1n\Big)^{n}\bigg)
=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\,L\Big(1+\frac1n\Big)\\[0.2cm]
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\,\int_1^{1+1/n}\frac1x\,dx=1.
\end{align}
The last limit follows from
$$
\frac1n\,\frac1{1+\frac1n}\leq\int_1^{1+1/n}\frac1x\,dx\leq\frac1n,
$$
obtained from $\frac1{1+\frac1n}\leq\frac1x\leq1$ for $x$ between $1$ and $1+\frac1n$.

Beautiful! Thank you ever so much, this has been plaguing me all day, and I just hadn't thought of plugging in this definition of e.

Let's use another representation:  $e=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$.
$L:(0,\infty)\to (-\infty,\infty)$ is continuous, strictly increasing and unbounded from below and above. Therefore it possesses an inverse function $E:(-\infty,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$.  Because the derivative of $L$ is strictly positive, $E$ is differentiable.  From the chain rule, the inverse function satisfies $E'(x) = \frac{1}{L'(E(x))}= E(x)$. This shows that $E$ has derivatives at all orders with $E^{(k)}(x) = E(x)$.  As $E(0)=1$, the Taylor series of $E$ at $0$ is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k /k!$. In particular, the number we are after, $E(1)$, is equal to the above representation of $e$.
Appendix: Equivalence of the representations
Let $x_n = (1+ \frac{1}{n})^n$.
Use the binomial theorem to obtain
$$ x_n=\sum_{k=0}^n n^{-k} \binom{n}{k} = 1+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{ (1-\frac1n)  \cdots (1- \frac{k-1}{n})}{k!} $$
Consider the righthand side.

$x_n \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$ and therefore $\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$. Note that the series on the right converges by comparison with $1+ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}$.
Let $M$ be a positive integer and let $n>M$. Then $x_n$ bounded from below by $1+(1-\frac{M}{n})^M\sum_{k=1}^M \frac{1}{k!}$. As  $n\to\infty$ this tends to  $\sum_{k=0}^M \frac{1}{k!}$, and therefore $\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n \ge \sum_{k=0}^M \frac{1}{k!}$. As this is true for all $M$, we have $\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n \ge \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$.

Putting both together we have that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ exists and is finite, and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+ \frac{1}{n})^n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}.$$
Note: of course we can avoid the $\liminf /\limsup$.This would make the argument a little longer.
